# Will I lose Mortarboard badge if I am downvoted?

Tags: discussion, badges

I was awarded the **mortarboard** badge for earning over the 200 points maximum, but I was just barely over it. If someone downvotes my answer or chooses a different correct answer from the one you had gotten 15 points for earlier, will you lose the badge?

Comment: FWIW even if badges got revoked, your Mortarbadge badge still wouldn't because downvotes are ignored when calculating for these badges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry, badges once award are never taken back (unless gained through cheating, in which case developers can still step in and remove the badges).

However Tag badges are taken back. Regular badges are indeed not un-awarded

[Update from Martijn's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225415/lose-mortarboard-badge-if-downvoted#comment736560_225416)

Conclusion : Will I lose Mortarboard badge if I am downvoted?

[image]

<sub><sub>It is friday today.</sub></sub>

Comment: Tag badges *are* taken back. Regular badges are indeed not un-awarded (unless gained through cheating, in which case developers can still step in and remove the badges).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly badges besides tag badges are not unawarded.

Secondly that's not quite how mortarboard works. It's about hitting the daily rep cap, which a downvote will lower, so that going over, say, 20 answer upvotes will not make you impune to downvotes.